# Best way to store addin settings in Excel addin

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

I am developing an excel addin in Visual Studio. This addin is communicating with WCF service.

I want to give user ability to change WCF server address in Excel addin. So I have a Windows Form and I saving the string as Property.

Now I store server address in:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.serviceAddress
```

The server address must:

-be changeable through Excel addin

-server address needs to be stored after Excel is closed

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: If it works, what would you consider "better"?

Comment: Why is this also tagged C?

Comment: Sorry C was mistyped.

Comment: I am begginer and I want to hear opinion about this from more experienced users. This should be a commercial addin, so I want to be as perfect as it could be.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Backstage Info tab for storing user specific settings.

How to customize back stage?
[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2009/12/04/using-office-2010-extensibility-schemas-with-vsto-addins-for-beta-2-stephen-peters.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851(v=office.14).aspx)

You need to decide where to store the settings, I had Sql server to store user details like these settings and favourite documents. You can store it in a file stored in roaming profile area and read from the file while opening excel.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using an XML based file with your settings where you can read and write changes back. Actually, it is up to you what format is to use - JSON, XML and etc. I think it will solve the points you mnetioned in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own file in Folders like ProgramData or AppData to save settings.

For internal structuring purposes, you can use your defined XML, a DataTable based XML, a DataSet based XML, object [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms233843.aspx), CSV etc.

Easiest is [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) based XML. Use methods like WriteXML and ReadXML with Schema Mode